# simplest approach of dynamically adding components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

currently working on react. I have two components lets say ad and home . Inside home components i have one image and on click event of that image i want to render ad inside home component below image. Is there any simples method . thank you!

Comment: Maintain an isOpen state in Home component. Toggle it on click of image and based on this state render the AD conditionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this. i think this is what you want

```
//dynamically generate div 
let DynamicDiv=()=>{
    return (<div>
        <p>i am here</p>
    </div>)
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      visible:false //visibility of Component
    }

    this.divVisiblity=this.divVisiblity.bind(this) //function is bind when user clicks on pic
  }
  divVisiblity(){
    //this function will get called when user clicks on function
    this.setState(()=>{return {visible:!this.state.visible}}) //changes visible state of Component when user clicks

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="App">
      {/* onClick is assigned function named divVisiblity */}
        <img onClick={this.divVisiblity} src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="test"/>
          {/*this is ternary if else statement in js */}
      {/* if visible = true ,display Component else dont  */}
      <div> 
        {this.state.visible && <DynamicDiv/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think that will help to you.

export default class HomeComponent extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            renderAdComponent: false
        };
        this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    onClickHandler() {
        this.setState({renderAdComponent: !this.state.renderAdComponent})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Image onClick={this.onClickHandler}/>
                {this.state.renderAdComponent ? <AdComponent/> : null}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What @sdkcy suggested is okay but the ternary operator isn't really needed. You can do the following

`{ this.state.isAdShown && <ComponentToShow /> }`

This gets rid of the useless `: null` result.